# Concatenate + Ternary

Tags: php

In PHP, is there a way to concatenate two strings using a ternary conditional?

```
<?= 'something' . (true) ? 'else' : 'not'; ?>
```

When I try that, all I get is `else` rather than the desired `something else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equal to

```
<?= ('something' . (true)) ? 'else' : 'not'; ?>
```

Because according to the [table of Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) the operator `.` has higher precedence of ternary operator `?:`

So, you must force the priority with parentheses as explained by [Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28282509/1049668)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that. Appears to be the most technically precise response. Might consider adding the correct way also just in case others get tripped up and don't see the other responses.

Comment: @cantera Just to say it it's not because of the left associative of the ternary operator! It's because the concatenation operator has a higher precedence then ternary operator!

Comment: @cantera The associative part of a operator is only relevant if operators has the same precedence which is not the case her!

Comment: Indeed, left associative means that `a-b-c` would be read as `(a-b)-c`, the power function on calculators is for instance right associative `a^b^c=a^(b^c)`.

Comment: My mistake. I'm thinking to multiple ternary operators.

Comment: -1 because all you've done is point out what the code is actually doing instead. Which is fine, but it doesn't actually solve the problem. Which is not.

Comment: @RubberDuck: the question is not how to resolve it, but why that doesn't work. If you reread the question, you never find a question for resolution...

Comment: @RubberDuck I answered after three other answers that tell (s)he how to solve. But nobody has said explicity why the code print "else". I don't expected to be the accepted answer, for this it's not so verbose. It's obviuos by question that cantera knows how works a ternary operator. HIwever If it's really important for you, I could add more infos :-).

Answer (score 10):

Just put brackets around the entire ternary operator like this:

```
<?= 'something' . ((true) ? ' else' : ' not'); ?>
```

Why do you have to do that?

The answer is: operator precedence

See the manual for more information:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to put your ternary in brackets though. Try this:

```
<?php echo 'something '.((true) ? 'else' : 'not'); ?>
```