# Ternary operator to change class

Tags: php

I have:

```
 echo '<ul id="my-list" class="'.(true) ? 'classA' : 'classB'.'">';
```

But the HTML is not being output, only the text classA is being outputted to the page.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Explanation why you have to put parentheses around it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28282509/3933332

Answer (score 1):

Try to use additionnal parenthesis :

```
echo '<ul id="my-list" class="'.((true) ? 'classA' : 'classB').'">';
```

Because the concatenation operator( like the majority of operators in php)  will cast the object to its right to the same type as the object on its left .